# SQL query to select records based on criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a bit of a SQL n00b moment. Say I have a property website with two tables: `properties` and `features`, with a table that joins them. If I have a search form, how can I structure my query to select only properties with **all** of the selected criteria?

For example, criteria would be POSTed in the form of an array from checkboxes:

```
Array
(
    [features] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
        )
)
```

How can I select records from my `properties` that have features with the IDs of 1, 2 and 5 (and possibly others), but properties that only have one or two are not matched?

Comment: Can you put fiddle for it : sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @BugFinder Well I've tried using `IN`, but that returns records that have *any* of the selected criteria, as opposed to records with *all* of the criteria selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your join table for the features of interest, then group by property and restrict the resultset to only those groups that contain the desired number of records:

```
SELECT   properties.*
FROM     properties JOIN propfeatures USING (property_id)
WHERE    propfeatures.feature_id IN (1,2,5)
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT propfeatures.feature_id) = 3
```

Of course, if uniqueness is guaranteed, you can save on the `DISTINCT` operation and simply use `COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what the above is doing. Could it break it down a little more please?

Comment: @MartinBean: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`? It aggregates multiple records into a single result row: in this case, all records with the same `property_id`.  Since the `WHERE` clause filters `propfeatures` for only those features of interest, and the `HAVING` clause restricts the results to those groups that contained 3 records, we therefore select only those properties that have all 3 of the desired features.

Answer (score 0):

If the `properties` and `features` tables are joined by a column `feature_id` in `properties` table to `id` in `features` table, then we can do this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `properties` AS a JOIN `features` AS b WHERE 
a.`feature_id`=b.`id` AND b.`id` IN (1,2,5) ORDER BY a.`feature_id` ASC;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "*but properties that only have one or two are not matched?*"

Comment: @eggyal - oh!, sorry to have missed that part..the test table i used did not take care of that. Your solution will work in that case. +1 for that.